# Django failed on creation foreign key migration

Tags: django, python-3.x, migration

In my project I have custom user model. When I try to create foreign key to user model, migration failed with

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1005, 'Can\'t create table `coins`.`#sql-165_8f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
```

Until this moment everything was good.

Now for this model code not work

```
class CoQuestion(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
text = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('text'))
co_user = models.ForeignKey('custom_auth.CoinUser', verbose_name=_('user'))

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'co_question'
    verbose_name = _('question')
    verbose_name_plural = _('questions')
```

But for this was work

```
class CoBets(models.Model):
    """
    Describes a model of bets
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    co_user = models.ForeignKey('custom_auth.CoinUser', verbose_name=_('user'))
    co_lot = models.ForeignKey('CoLot', verbose_name=_('lot'), related_name='bets')
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('size'),
                               validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))],
                               default=0.01)
    dt = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('date'),
                              default=datetime(2014, 12, 12, 15, 44, 37, 856544))
    co_rejection = models.ForeignKey('CoRejection', verbose_name=_('rejection'),
                                     null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'co_bets'
        verbose_name = _('bet')
        verbose_name_plural = _('bets')
```

This is migration that create 1st model

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='CoQuestion',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(serialize=False, primary_key=True)),
        ('text', models.TextField(verbose_name='text')),
        ('co_user', models.ForeignKey(verbose_name='user', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
    ],
    options={
        'verbose_name': 'question',
        'db_table': 'co_question',
        'verbose_name_plural': 'questions',
        'managed': True,
    },
    bases=(models.Model,),
),
```

And this add field to 2nd model
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='cobets',
            name='co_user',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),

Comment: same problem here. found that only django's own tables can not be migrate and produce the error.